# How do I define dynamic paths in React when the path name is generated from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, routes, react-router

My application pulls resources from my database and I want to make the resource name the path name. For now, I have an array of example resource names. Resources can be updated, deleted etc. therefore you have to assume the array could contain any values, not the predefined ones:

```
fetchResources() {
    // fetch the resource names from the database

    // example of fetched data:
    var fetched = ["Resource 1", "Resource 2", "Resource 3"];

    return (fetched);
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Resources</h1>
            <p>This is where the students can view the resources the staff create.</p>

            <div>
                {this.fetchResources().map(resource => <div>
                    <h3><Link to="/student/resources/RESOURCE_NAME">{resource}</Link></h3>
                </div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is not my App.js. This is a separate .js file called Resource.js. The resource will be rendered in a file called ResourceTemplate.js. My app routes are also in a separate file called AppRoutes.js. An example of my routes is:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={["/", "/public/home"]} component={AppHomePage}/>
    ...more routes...
</Switch>
```

The component is imported at the top of the file. So, how do I have a route that changes depending on which resource is being displayed, for example:

```
<Route path="/resources/RESOURCE_NAME" component={ResourceTemplate}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you can fetch the url for every resource

```
// example of fetched data:
  var fetched = [{"name": "Resource 1", "url": "resource1"},{"name": "Resource 2", "url": "resource2"},{"name": "Resource 3", "url": "resource3"}];
```

And then use string interpolation when you do the map and pass the url like this

```
{this.fetchResources().map(resource => (
  <div>
    <h3><Link to={`/student/resources/${resource.url}`}>{resource.name}</Link></h3>
  </div>))}
```

Then your route has to be:

```
<Route path="/resources/:id" component={ResourceTemplate}/>
```